# Consume rabbitmq topic exchange .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm learning Rabbitmq in .net envirorment and trying to publish and consuming in a topic exchange, but my consumer doesn't get the message published.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    CreatePublisher();
    CreateConsumer();
 }

public static void CreatePublisher() 
 {
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", 
     UserName = "myUser", Password = "myPass" };
  using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
  using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

  channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: 
     ExchangeType.Topic);

  var message = "testeee";
  var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
  channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "logs",
     routingKey: "logs",
     basicProperties: null,
     body: body);
  Console.WriteLine($" [x] Sent {message}");

  Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
}

public static void CreateConsumer()
{
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", 
   UserName = "myUser", Password = "myPass" };
  using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
  using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

  channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: 
   ExchangeType.Topic);

  // declare a server-named queue
  var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
  channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                      exchange: "logs",
                      routingKey: "logs");

  Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for logs.");

  var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        byte[] body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine($" [x] {message}");
    };
    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                         autoAck: true,
                         consumer: consumer);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It doesn't consume the published message, I for me it should work because the 2 routing keys matches. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate consumer and publisher and run independently on two consoles instead of having them in the same file.

Comment: It is not correct, you can write pub/sub on the same console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Exchange does not hold messages, so if you publish a message before you bind a queue to the exchange by creating a consumer, the message is lost.
In your code you publish a message before you bind the queue to the exchange.

From rabbitMq tutorial:

> The messages will be lost if no queue is bound to the exchange yet

The solution is to call the `BasicPublish` after you call `createConsumer()` like so:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    CreatePublisher();
    CreateConsumer();
    PublishMessage();
 }

public static void CreatePublisher() 
 {
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", 
     UserName = "myUser", Password = "myPass" };
  using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
  using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

  channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: 
     ExchangeType.Topic);

 
  

  Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
}

public static void PublishMessage()
{
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", 
  UserName = "myUser", Password = "myPass" };
  using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
  using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

  var message = "testeee";
  var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
  channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "logs",
     routingKey: "logs",
     basicProperties: null,
     body: body);
  Console.WriteLine($" [x] Sent {message}");
}

public static void CreateConsumer()
{
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", 
   UserName = "myUser", Password = "myPass" };
  using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
  using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

  channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: 
   ExchangeType.Topic);

  // declare a server-named queue
  var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
  channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                      exchange: "logs",
                      routingKey: "logs");

  Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for logs.");

  var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        byte[] body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine($" [x] {message}");
    };
    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                         autoAck: true,
                         consumer: consumer);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```